# A HTML form seems correct but doesn't submit

Tags: html, forms

I've recently extended a working form I had but now the form doesn't submit. I thought perhaps it was due to the addition of the Select field, but on removing that the form still doesn't submit.

I then thought perhaps the Divs causing issues, but can't seem to work out why they would?

Without any additional DIVS etc. the form works as expected.

I've also tried adding an id to the form then form attributes to each input/select field but still no success.

```
<form action="jobs.php" class="search-form" method="get">
<div class="form-container">
    <div class="box-select">
        <div class="select">
            <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Keywords" style="padding: 28px 15px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="select">
            <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" style="padding: 28px 15px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="select">
            <select name="category">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                <option value="">Accounts and Finance</option>
                <option value="">Actuarial / Statistics</option>
                <option value="">Architect / Interior Design</option>
                <option value="">Arts / Creative / Media</option>
                <option value="">Cleaning / Security / Maintenance</option>
                <option value="">Clerical / Administrative</option>
                <option value="">Construction / Real Estate</option>
                <option value="">Customer Service / Telesales</option>
                <option value="">Education / Lecturing</option>
                <option value="">Executive / Professional / Management </option>
                <option value="">Hotel / Restaurant / Travel / Leisure</option>
                <option value="">Human Resources</option>
                <option value="">Information Technologies / Telecommunication</option>
                <option value="">Logistics / Shipping / Warehouse</option>
                <option value="">Manufacturing - Production </option>
                <option value="">Others</option>
                <option value="">Public Relations & Communication </option>
                <option value="">Purchasing / Procurement</option>
                <option value="">Retail / Showroom / Counter / Exhibition Sales</option>
                <option value="">Sales & Marketing</option>
                <option value="">Technical and Engineering</option>
                <option value="">Training and Development</option>
                <option value="">Wellness / Fitness </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="select">
            <button class="button" type="button">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone point me at what I'm doing wrong here please.

Comment: i know it's kinda late but did you get a solution?

Answer (score 4):

As said in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit)

> `<input>` elements of type submit are rendered as buttons. When the
>   click event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button),
>   the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server.

The type of your button needs to be `submit` if the `form` is to be submitted on `button` click.
Thus, replace

```
<button class="button" type="button">Search</button>
```

with

```
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
```

Comment: Adding to this, you don't need to specify `type="submit"` at all. Buttons without a specified type always default to `submit`, so you can just do `<button class="button">Search</button>`.